# Finding caller when not visible in backtrace

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My application is hitting 100% CPU and continuously consuming more RAM. I have used instruments and found the offending line of code, it seems its being called in some sort of an infinite loop. However the backtrace does not give me any indication of the caller only a library function that is calling it.

I have searched the entire codebase and have not located any user code calling the offending function.

I'm looking for a way to dig deeper and discover what may be causing `_setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion` to be repeatedly called

Backtrace:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 3.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000105bf6187 Demo App`-[UIImageView(self=0x00007fa291f85660, _cmd="setTintColor:", color=0x000060000004d020) setTintColor:] at UIImageView+Utils.m:21
    frame #1: 0x000000010677d0bc UIKit`+[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 560
    frame #2: 0x000000010677d599 UIKit`+[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 99
    frame #3: 0x0000000106b24792 UIKit`-[UIButton _updateImageView] + 1005
    frame #4: 0x0000000106b24fc4 UIKit`-[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 211
    frame #5: 0x000000010678a4f1 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1439
    frame #6: 0x000000010d29149a QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
    frame #7: 0x000000010d295589 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 401
    frame #8: 0x0000000106774531 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 662
    frame #9: 0x0000000107301063 UIKit`-[UIInputSetHostView layoutIfNeeded] + 104
    frame #10: 0x0000000106f7a08e UIKit`-[_UIRemoteKeyboards ignoreLayoutNotifications:] + 27
    frame #11: 0x0000000107311838 UIKit`__43-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]_block_invoke + 125
    frame #12: 0x000000010677b6ec UIKit`+[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 90
    frame #13: 0x000000010731152f UIKit`-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 702
    frame #14: 0x00000001073089d1 UIKit`-[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 50
    frame #15: 0x0000000106ea9f9e UIKit`-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1081
    frame #16: 0x00000001068ecacd UIKit`-[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews] + 81
    frame #17: 0x00000001073d1cc7 UIKit`-[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 690
```

```

Comment: Can you post the content of your UIImageView extension? It seems like something within laying out subviews is causing the view to once again, layout Subviews. We'll need to see what your code is actually doing here to know more.

Comment: The times I've caused this for myself, I had a **@property someval (setter=setSomeval:)** and within setSomeval:, I would use self.someval = p, causing an infinite recursive call to the setter. Solution: _someval = p;

Comment: It turns out that the extension method being called was named the same thing as a UIImageView method. I was able to make a call to super within the method and it resolved the issue.